# Filtering with Linq to Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I've inherited an app I need to update where I can't alter the db's table structure.

```
ID | PromoID | VersionDate | Type
1    P0001     01/03/2013    Live
2    P0002     02/03/2013    Live
3    P0001     02/04/2012    Draft
4    P0003     01/03/2013    Live
5    P0003     01/02/2013    Live
```

So, the original dev had this primitive concept of versioning records. What I need to do is create a linq query that returns the most recent version of all "Live" versions, but I also need to ensure no record is returned if any of its versions has a type of "Draft"

I have this:

```
var records = from r in _context.Promotions
              let maxversion =
                             (from v in _context.Promotions
                              where v.PromoID == t.PromoID
                              select v.VersionDate).Max()
              where r.Type == "Live"
              && r.VersionDate == maxversion
              select r
```

But I have no idea how I can filter out all records that have the same PromoID where one of them is has type "Draft". From the data I supplied, I need to have both records #1 and #3 excised because they share the same PromoId and #3 has a Type of draft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var records = from r in _context.Promotions
              let maxversion =
                             (from v in _context.Promotions
                              where v.PromoID == t.PromoID
                              select v.VersionDate).Max()
              where r.Type == "Live"
              && r.VersionDate == maxversion
              && !_context.Promotions.Any(p => p.PromoID = t.PromoID && p.Type=="Draft")
              select r
```

Answer (score 2):

This should also do it, the result IEnumerable (when evaluated) should still only generate a single query to the database;

```
var ids_with_drafts = from p1 in _context.Promotions
                      where p1.Type == "Draft"
                      select p1.PromotionID;

var result = from promotion in _context.Promotions
             where !ids_with_drafts.Contains(promotion.PromotionID)
             group promotion by promotion.PromotionID
             into grp
             select grp.OrderByDescending(x => x.VersionDate).First();
```